# Catering to plus sign in username in Django

Tags: django, django-allauth

With my current setup, I get errors when trying to sign up with a plus sign in the username eg: "user+name". I am using django allauth

How to I cater to this, or at least exclude the plus sign (and any others) from the username field?

For one, the profile url doesn't work:

```
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', 'single_user', name='single_user'),
```

Sign up works, but then I get:

```
Reverse for 'single_user' with arguments '(<SimpleLazyObject: <User: user+name>>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['u/(?P<username>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

Not sure if this is an allauth specific issue or not - but a solution either way would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used some of dylrei's wording to correctly search for another option, found something that seems to have worked:

```
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', 'single_user', name='single_user'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used allauth, but I suspect your regex is wrong. I think you want this:

```
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[\w\+]+)/$', 'single_user', name='single_user'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried your suggestions, got this error straight away: Reverse for 'single_user' with arguments '(<User: pete>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['u/(?P<username>\\W+)/$']

Comment: Edited above. Wanted [\w\+]+, not \W. Sorry. Not sure that's actually the problem, however. There are several other questions in SO with that error message, but it's hard to know what to try next with the given information.